# How to set Id field and query it in GAE datestore via JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I want to set the Id field with type of Long. However, when I query it, I got this exeception:

```
Cannot access field id on type
```

and this is my annotation for this query

```
@NamedQuery(name = Q.User.FindById, query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id") })
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Cannot access field id on type com.j.model.User
    at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JavaQueryCompiler.getType(JavaQueryCompiler.java:552)
    at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JavaQueryCompiler.getType(JavaQueryCompiler.java:529)
    at org.datanucleus.query.symbol.SymbolTable.getType(SymbolTable.java:118)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.PrimaryExpression.bind(PrimaryExpression.java:118)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.DyadicExpression.bind(DyadicExpression.java:85)
    at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JavaQueryCompiler.compileFilter(JavaQueryCompiler.java:299)
    at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JPQLCompiler.compile(JPQLCompiler.java:75)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery.compileInternal(AbstractJPQLQuery.java:246)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.setImplicitParameter(Query.java:690)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAQuery.setParameter(JPAQuery.java:428)
```

I have been digging around for this, some suggest to do with Key and getname. quiote confuse, how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: posting the class, its metadata, and the message+stack trace would be a prerequisite